# Issues with OpenGL on a remote Ubuntu 20.04 machine with NVIDIA GTX 1070

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xfce, opengl, dbus

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 machine with an NVIDIA 1070 that I am connecting to with a laptop also running Ubuntu 20.04 with an NVIDIA GeForce MX150. OpenGL seems to work just fine on each individually, glxgears works fine when running using a monitor on the remote machine and it works fine on my laptop. However I can't get anything that needs openGL to work when connecting remotely.

My understanding is that I cannot simply X forward a window/GUI application that relies on opengl. When I ssh into the remote from the terminal, `xclock` and other x forwarding works just fine, but when I run `glxgears` I get the following error:

```
Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  32
Current serial number in output stream:  33
```

When I use x2go to login to the remote and run `glxgears` on the remote terminal, it crashes the session and closes it out.

Also, my understanding is that x2go would forward the information to be rendered on the local machine, but VNC instead renders the graphics on the remote and then sends the image to the local machine, so I thought that would work better. I tried and still when connected to the remote using a VNC server and I run `glxgears` on the remote, it just crashes the connection and closes it.

Can someone assist in getting OpenGL graphics to work when connected to a remote machine? It's not even that I want it to run on the remote NVIDIA card, I don't even care if it runs on my local CPU, I just need it to not crash.

Additionally, it has been quite a pain to get all the proper CUDA versions and NVIDIA drivers installed such that they work well with various machine learning projects being used, i.e. projects requiring specific PyTorch versions, so ideally I can use the improved speed of x2go over VNC and just render the graphics on my local MX150 without messing around too much with the NVIDIA drivers/etc on the remote.

I've included below the `glxinfo` for both my local and remote machine, obtained when using an attached monitor since glxinfo also will not work when executed remotely. I deleted the trail end of some of the extensions and glxinfo command to fit it all in.

Local glxinfo:

```
$ glxinfo name of display: :1 display: :1 screen: 0 direct rendering: Yes server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation server glx version string: 1.4 server glx extensions: GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_libglvnd, GLX_EXT_stereo_tree, GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_NV_copy_image, GLX_NV_delay_before_swap, GLX_NV_float_buffer, GLX_NV_multigpu_context, GLX_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation client glx version string: 1.4 client glx extensions: GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_stereo_tree, GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_NV_copy_buffer, GLX_NV_copy_image, GLX_NV_delay_before_swap, GLX_NV_float_buffer, GLX_NV_multigpu_context, GLX_NV_multisample_coverage, GLX_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge, GLX_NV_swap_group, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync GLX version: 1.4 GLX extensions: GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_stereo_tree, GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_NV_copy_image, GLX_NV_delay_before_swap, GLX_NV_float_buffer, GLX_NV_multigpu_context, GLX_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info): Dedicated video memory: 2048 MB Total available memory: 2048 MB Currently available dedicated video memory: 1417 MB OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce MX150/PCIe/SSE2 OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.103.01 OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA OpenGL core profile context flags: (none) OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile OpenGL core profile extensions: GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_base_instance, GL_ARB_bindless_texture, GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_buffer_storage, GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, GL_ARB_clip_control, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_compute_shader, GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size,

OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.103.01 OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA OpenGL context flags: (none) OpenGL profile mask: (none) OpenGL extensions: GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_base_instance, GL_ARB_bindless_texture, GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_buffer_storage, GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, GL_ARB_clip_control, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_compatibility, GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_compute_shader, GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image, GL_ARB_cull_distance, GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_derivative_control, GL_ARB_direct_state_access, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex,

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 470.103.01 OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20 OpenGL ES profile extensions: GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a, GL_EXT_EGL_image_external_wrap_modes, GL_EXT_base_instance, GL_EXT_blend_func_extended, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_buffer_storage, GL_EXT_clear_texture, GL_EXT_clip_control, GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance, GL_EXT_color_buffer_float, GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float, GL_EXT_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_sub_texture, GL_EXT_conservative_depth, GL_EXT_copy_image, GL_EXT_debug_label, GL_EXT_depth_clamp, GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer, GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query, GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed, GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_EXT_draw_transform_feedback,
```

Remote glxinfo:

```
name of display: :0.0
display: :0 screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context,  
GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,  
GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float,  
GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age,  
GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,  
GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_libglvnd,  
GLX_EXT_stereo_tree, GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear,  
GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,  
GLX_NV_copy_image, GLX_NV_delay_before_swap, GLX_NV_float_buffer,  
GLX_NV_multigpu_context, GLX_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge,  
GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_swap_control,  
GLX_SGI_video_sync 
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context,  
GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,  
GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float,  
GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age,  
GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,  
GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,  
GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_stereo_tree, GLX_EXT_swap_control,  
GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,  
GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_NV_copy_buffer,  
GLX_NV_copy_image, GLX_NV_delay_before_swap, GLX_NV_float_buffer,  
GLX_NV_multigpu_context, GLX_NV_multisample_coverage,  
GLX_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge, GLX_NV_swap_group,  
GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_swap_control,  
GLX_SGI_video_sync 
GLX version: 1.4
```

GLX extensions:

```
GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context,  
GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,  
GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float,  
GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age,  
GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,  
GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_stereo_tree,  
GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear,  
GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,  
GLX_NV_copy_image, GLX_NV_delay_before_swap, GLX_NV_float_buffer,  
GLX_NV_multigpu_context, GLX_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge,  
GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_swap_control,  
GLX_SGI_video_sync 
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
Dedicated video memory: 8192 MB 
Total available memory: 8192 MB 
Currently available dedicated video memory: 7729 MB 
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.42.01
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture,  
GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index,  
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.42.01
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture,  
GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index,  
GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility,  
GL_ARB_ES3_2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility,  
GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_base_instance, GL_ARB_bindless_texture,  
GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_buffer_storage,  
GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, GL_ARB_clip_control,  
GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_compatibility,  
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 470.42.01
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a, GL_EXT_EGL_image_external_wrap_modes,  
GL_EXT_base_instance, GL_EXT_blend_func_extended, GL_EXT_blend_minmax,  
GL_EXT_buffer_storage, GL_EXT_clear_texture, GL_EXT_clip_control,  
GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance, GL_EXT_color_buffer_float,  
GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float, GL_EXT_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_sub_texture,  
GL_EXT_conservative_depth, GL_EXT_copy_image, GL_EXT_debug_label,  
GL_EXT_depth_clamp, GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer,  
GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query, GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed,  
GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_EXT_draw_transform_feedback,  
GL_EXT_float_blend, GL_EXT_frag_depth, GL_EXT_geometry_point_size,  
GL_EXT_geometry_shader, GL_EXT_gpu_shader5, GL_EXT_map_buffer_range,  
GL_EXT_memory_object, GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, GL_EXT_multi_draw_indirect,  
GL_EXT_multisample_compatibility, GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture,  
GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture2,  
GL_EXT_multiview_texture_multisample, GL_EXT_multiview_timer_query,  
GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp,  
GL_EXT_post_depth_coverage, GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box,  
GL_EXT_raster_multisample, GL_EXT_render_snorm, GL_EXT_robustness,  
GL_EXT_sRGB, GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control, GL_EXT_semaphore,  
GL_EXT_semaphore_fd, GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects,  
GL_EXT_shader_group_vote, GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions,  
GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks,  
GL_EXT_shader_non_constant_global_initializers, GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod,  
GL_EXT_shadow_samplers, GL_EXT_sparse_texture, GL_EXT_sparse_texture2,  
GL_EXT_tessellation_point_size, GL_EXT_tessellation_shader,  
GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_buffer,  
GL_EXT_texture_compression_bptc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1,  
GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc,  
GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic,  
GL_EXT_texture_filter_minmax, GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888,  
GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_EXT_texture_norm16,  
GL_EXT_texture_query_lod, GL_EXT_texture_rg, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8,  
GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_texture_shadow_lod,  
GL_EXT_texture_storage, GL_EXT_texture_view, GL_EXT_unpack_subimage,  
GL_EXT_window_rectangles, GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced,  
GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent, GL_KHR_context_flush_control,  
GL_KHR_debug, GL_KHR_no_error, GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile,  
GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior, GL_KHR_robustness,  
GL_KHR_shader_subgroup, GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr,  
GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr,  
GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d,  
GL_NVX_blend_equation_advanced_multi_draw_buffers, GL_NV_bgr,  
GL_NV_bindless_texture, GL_NV_blend_equation_advanced,  
GL_NV_blend_equation_advanced_coherent, GL_NV_blend_minmax_factor,  
GL_NV_clip_space_w_scaling, GL_NV_conditional_render,  
GL_NV_conservative_raster, GL_NV_conservative_raster_pre_snap_triangles,
```

x2go crash log:

I suppose most importantly, I've pasted below my .xsession-x2go-errors log file which seems to describe the crash.

```
XSession-x2go: X session started for user at Sun 10 Apr 2022 06:13:35 PM EDT
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-OdqKZHPfkR,guid=aed0609654ccd7e5772d2df36253568f
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:50
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/user/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: warning: error sending to systemd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
xhost:  must be on local machine to add or remove hosts.
localuser:user being added to access control list
xhost:  must be on local machine to add or remove hosts.
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: warning: error sending to systemd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: warning: error sending to systemd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/user/.x2go/C-user-50-1649628812_stDXFCE_dp24/ssh-agent.PID
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting STARTUP=/usr/bin/im-launch /usr/bin/env LD_LIBRARY_PATH= xfce4-session
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/user/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MOTD_SHOWN=pam
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting X2GO_SESSION=user-50-1649628812_stDXFCE_dp24
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PULSE_CLIENTCONFIG=/home/user/.x2go/C-user-50-1649628812_stDXFCE_dp24/.pulse-client.conf
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SSH_CONNECTION=some_ip_address some_port some_ip_address some_port
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=dumb
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting X2GO_AGENT_PID=7023
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:50
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=2
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SSH_CLIENT=some_ip_address some_port some_port
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-OdqKZHPfkR,guid=aed0609654ccd7e5772d2df36253568f
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XSESSION_EXEC=xfce4-session
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
dbus-update-activation-environment: warning: error sending to systemd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
dbus-update-activation-environment: warning: error sending to systemd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
gpg-agent[7362]: WARNING: "--write-env-file" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg-agent: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one

(xfce4-session:7218): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 18:13:35.832: gpg-agent returned no PID in the variables

(xfwm4:7364): xfwm4-WARNING **: 18:13:35.924: XSync extension too old (3.0).

(xfwm4:7364): xfwm4-WARNING **: 18:13:35.926: The display does not support the XComposite extension.

(xfwm4:7364): xfwm4-WARNING **: 18:13:35.927: The display does not support the XPresent extension.

(xfwm4:7364): xfwm4-WARNING **: 18:13:35.927: Compositing manager disabled.

(xfsettingsd:7373): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: 18:13:35.994: Your XI is too old (1.3) version 1.4 is required.

(xfsettingsd:7373): xfsettingsd-WARNING **: 18:13:35.994: Failed to create device filter

** (wrapper-2.0:7398): WARNING **: 18:13:36.301: No outputs have backlight property

(xfce4-session:7218): GLib-WARNING **: 18:13:36.304: GChildWatchSource: Exit status of a child process was requested but ECHILD was received by waitpid(). See the documentation of g_child_watch_source_new() for possible causes.

(wrapper-2.0:7399): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:13:36.305: g_file_new_for_path: assertion 'path != NULL' failed

(wrapper-2.0:7399): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:13:36.305: g_file_monitor_file: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed

(wrapper-2.0:7399): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 18:13:36.305: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(wrapper-2.0:7399): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 18:13:36.305: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(wrapper-2.0:7399): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:13:36.305: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkToggleButton to a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, but the widget is already inside a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, please remove the widget from its existing container first.

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


** (xiccd:7441): WARNING **: 18:13:36.364: EDID is empty

** (xiccd:7441): CRITICAL **: 18:13:36.366: unable to create profile: failed to obtain org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile auth

(wrapper-2.0:7398): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:13:36.373: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner PowerManagerButton)

** (xiccd:7441): CRITICAL **: 18:13:36.376: unable to create profile: failed to obtain org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile auth

** (xiccd:7441): CRITICAL **: 18:13:36.376: unable to create profile: failed to obtain org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile auth

** (light-locker:7434): ERROR **: 18:13:36.379: Environment variable XDG_SESSION_PATH not set. Is LightDM running?

(wrapper-2.0:7399): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:13:36.382: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)

** (xiccd:7441): CRITICAL **: 18:13:36.385: failed to create colord device: failed to obtain org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device auth

(wrapper-2.0:7397): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:13:36.429: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner PulseaudioButton)
Tracker-Message: 18:13:36.433: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Tracker-Message: 18:13:36.433: Setting priority nice level to 19
Tracker-Message: 18:13:36.446: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Tracker-Message: 18:13:36.446: Setting priority nice level to 19
Failure: Module initialization failed

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:7476): GLib-CRITICAL **: 18:13:36.469: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:7476): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: 18:13:36.470: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (xfce4-screensaver:7459): WARNING **: 18:13:36.488: screensaver already running in this session

(wrapper-2.0:7400): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:13:36.590: Negative content width -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node button, owner XfceArrowButton)
blueman-applet 18.13.36 WARNING  PluginManager:147 __load_plugin: Not loading DhcpClient because its conflict has higher priority
blueman-applet 18.13.36 WARNING  PluginManager:147 __load_plugin: Not loading PPPSupport because its conflict has higher priority
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.

(xfce4-panel:7383): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 18:13:44.327: gtk_icon_theme_load_icon: assertion 'icon_name != NULL' failed
(xfce4-panel:7383): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 18:13:44.328: gtk_icon_theme_load_icon: assertion 'icon_name != NULL' failed
(xfce4-panel:7383): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 18:13:44.348: gtk_icon_theme_load_icon: assertion 'icon_name != NULL' failed
X connection to :50.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.458: blueman-tray: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.458: polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.458: wrapper-2.0: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.458: blueman-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.458: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.458: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.458: wrapper-2.0: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.458: evolution-alarm-notify: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.458: wrapper-2.0: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.458: xfwm4: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.459: wrapper-2.0: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.459: xfdesktop: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.460: xfsettingsd: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.461: xfce4-panel: Fatal IO error 25 (Inappropriate ioctl for device) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.461: wrapper-2.0: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.462: Thunar: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.463: xfce4-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.
Gdk-Message: 18:13:44.463: wrapper-2.0: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :50.0.
(tracker-miner-fs:7482): Tracker-CRITICAL **: 18:13:44.470:   (Sparql buffer) Error in array-update: The connection is closed
(tracker-miner-fs:7482): Tracker-CRITICAL **: 18:13:44.471: Could not execute sparql: The connection is closed
Received signal:15->'Terminated'
(tracker-miner-fs:7482): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:13:44.471: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
(tracker-miner-fs:7482): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:13:44.471: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
(tracker-miner-fs:7482): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:13:44.472: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
Received signal:15->'Terminated'
OK
```